# Yum query for dependencies

Tags: yum

I want to update a package without updating the dependencies. Yum by default update dependencies as well. any help?

Comment: you can just install only the new version of the package

Answer (score 1):

Here is example with openssh

1)Find name of the package that you want to install: `yum list |grep openssh`

2)Download package: `yum install --downloadonly openssh.x86_64`

3)Find where exactly yum downloaded the file: `find /var/ -name "*openssh*"`

4)Install that package: `rpm -i --nodeps /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base/packages/openssh-6.6.1p1-31.el7.x86_64.rpm`

It's highly recommend install apps with all dependencies required. That's why people created package manager. You take risk when you install apps with `--nodeps`

Comment: Thanks. Can we do the same with yum as well?